# PayPal IPN returning blank POST or GET

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

I found a PayPal library for CodeIgniter recently and have been trying to receive variables back from PayPal. However nothing has been returning. I have tried to var_dump the GET and POST variables but nothing has been returning.

I have successfully made payments to PayPal but the return is always empty.

I have also removed csrf protection for PayPal, success and notification. IPN has been set in my PayPal account as well

This is the library I am using

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class paypal_lib {

    var $last_error;            // holds the last error encountered
    var $ipn_log;               // bool: log IPN results to text file?

    var $ipn_log_file;          // filename of the IPN log
    var $ipn_response;          // holds the IPN response from paypal   
    var $ipn_data = array();    // array contains the POST values for IPN
    var $fields = array();      // array holds the fields to submit to paypal

    var $submit_btn = '';       // Image/Form button
    var $button_path = '';      // The path of the buttons

    var $CI;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->helper('url');
        $this->CI->load->helper('form');
        $this->CI->load->config('paypallib_config');

        $sanbox = $this->CI->config->item('sandbox');
        $this->paypal_url = ($sanbox == TRUE)?'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr':'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

        $this->last_error = '';
        $this->ipn_response = '';

        $this->ipn_log_file = $this->CI->config->item('paypal_lib_ipn_log_file');
        $this->ipn_log = $this->CI->config->item('paypal_lib_ipn_log'); 

        $this->button_path = $this->CI->config->item('paypal_lib_button_path');

        // populate $fields array with a few default values.  See the paypal
        // documentation for a list of fields and their data types. These defaul
        // values can be overwritten by the calling script.
        $businessEmail = $this->CI->config->item('business');
        $this->add_field('business',$businessEmail);
        $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
        $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick');

        $this->add_field('currency_code', $this->CI->config->item('paypal_lib_currency_code'));
            $this->add_field('quantity', '1');
        $this->button('Pay Now!');
    }

    function button($value)
    {
        // changes the default caption of the submit button
        $this->submit_btn = form_submit('pp_submit', $value);
    }

    function image($file)
    {
        $this->submit_btn = '<input type="image" name="add" src="' . site_url($this->button_path .'/'. $file) . '" border="0" />';
    }


    function add_field($field, $value) 
    {
        // adds a key=>value pair to the fields array, which is what will be 
        // sent to paypal as POST variables.  If the value is already in the 
        // array, it will be overwritten.
        $this->fields[$field] = $value;
    }

    function paypal_auto_form() 
    {
        // this function actually generates an entire HTML page consisting of
        // a form with hidden elements which is submitted to paypal via the 
        // BODY element's onLoad attribute.  We do this so that you can validate
        // any POST vars from you custom form before submitting to paypal.  So 
        // basically, you'll have your own form which is submitted to your script
        // to validate the data, which in turn calls this function to create
        // another hidden form and submit to paypal.

        $this->button('Click here if you\'re not automatically redirected...');

        echo '<html>' . "\n";
        echo '<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>' . "\n";
        echo '<body style="text-align:center;" onLoad="document.forms[\'paypal_auto_form\'].submit();">' . "\n";
        echo '<p style="text-align:center;">Please wait, your order is being processed and you will be redirected to the paypal website.</p>' . "\n";
        echo $this->paypal_form('paypal_auto_form');
        echo '</body></html>';
    }

    function paypal_form($form_name='paypal_form') 
    {
        $str = '';
        $str .= '<form method="post" action="'.$this->paypal_url.'" name="'.$form_name.'"/>' . "\n";
        foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value)
            $str .= form_hidden($name, $value) . "\n";
        $str .= '<p>'. $this->submit_btn . '</p>';
        $str .= form_close() . "\n";

        return $str;
    }

    function validate_ipn()
    {
        // parse the paypal URL
        $url_parsed = parse_url($this->paypal_url);       

        // generate the post string from the _POST vars aswell as load the
        // _POST vars into an arry so we can play with them from the calling
        // script.
        $post_string = '';   
        if ($this->CI->input->post())
        {
            foreach ($this->CI->input->post() as $field=>$value)
            { 
                $this->ipn_data[$field] = $value;
                $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&'; 
            }
        }

        $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command

        // open the connection to paypal
        $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed['host'],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30); 
        if(!$fp)
        {
            // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
            // will be in the log.
            $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr";
            $this->log_ipn_results(false);       
            return false;
        } 
        else
        { 
            // Post the data back to paypal
            fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
            fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n"); 
            fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
            fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n"); 
            fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
            fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n"); 

            // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
            while(!feof($fp))
                $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 

            fclose($fp); // close connection
        }

        if (preg_match("/VERIFIED/",$this->ipn_response))
        {
            // Valid IPN transaction.
            $this->log_ipn_results(true);
            return true;         
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details.
            $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
            $this->log_ipn_results(false);  
            return false;
        }
    }

    function log_ipn_results($success) 
    {
        if (!$this->ipn_log) return;  // is logging turned off?

        // Timestamp
        $text = '['.date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '; 

        // Success or failure being logged?
        if ($success) $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
        else $text .= 'FAIL: '.$this->last_error."\n";

        // Log the POST variables
        $text .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n";
        foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value)
            $text .= "$key=$value, ";

        // Log the response from the paypal server
        $text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n ".$this->ipn_response;

        // Write to log
        $fp=fopen($this->ipn_log_file,'a');
        fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n"); 

        fclose($fp);  // close file
    }


    function dump() 
    {
        // Used for debugging, this function will output all the field/value pairs
        // that are currently defined in the instance of the class using the
        // add_field() function.

        ksort($this->fields);
        echo '<h2>ppal->dump() Output:</h2>' . "\n";
        echo '<code style="font: 12px Monaco, \'Courier New\', Verdana, Sans-serif;  background: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #D0D0D0; color: #002166; display: block; margin: 14px 0; padding: 12px 10px;">' . "\n";
        foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) echo '<strong>'. $key .'</strong>:    '. urldecode($value) .'<br/>';
        echo "</code>\n";
    }


    function curlPost($paypalurl,$paypalreturnarr)
    {

        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        foreach($paypalreturnarr as $key => $value) 
        {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        $ipnsiteurl=$paypalurl;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ipnsiteurl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }



}

?>
```

PayPal IPN config file

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Paypal IPN Class
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Use PayPal on Sandbox or Live
$config['sandbox'] = TRUE; // FALSE for live environment

// PayPal Business Email ID
$config['business'] = 'selleremail@email.com';

// If (and where) to log ipn to file
$config['paypal_lib_ipn_log_file'] = BASEPATH . 'logs/paypal_ipn.log';
$config['paypal_lib_ipn_log'] = TRUE;

// Where are the buttons located at 
$config['paypal_lib_button_path'] = 'buttons';

// What is the default currency?
$config['paypal_lib_currency_code'] = 'MYR';

?>
```

My Controller

```
public function pay(){
        //Set variables for paypal form
        $returnURL = site_url(AGENT_ROLE.$this->data['controller']."/Success"); //payment success url
        $cancelURL = site_url(AGENT_ROLE.$this->data['controller']."/Cancelled");//payment cancel url
        $notifyURL = site_url(AGENT_ROLE.$this->data['controller']."/Notification"); //ipn url
        //get particular product data
        $product = "test product";
        $userID = 1; //current user id
        $logo = base_url().'assets/images/logo/logo.png';

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('return', $returnURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('cancel_return', $cancelURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('notify_url', $notifyURL);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_name', $product);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('custom', $userID);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_number',  1);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('amount',  100.00);        
        $this->paypal_lib->image($logo);
        $this->paypal_lib->paypal_auto_form();
    }

    function success(){
        //get the transaction data
//        $paypalInfo = $this->input->get();
//        $paypalInfo2 = $this->input->post();
//        $data['item_number'] = $paypalInfo['item_number']; 
//        $data['txn_id'] = $paypalInfo["tx"];
//        $data['payment_amt'] = $paypalInfo["amt"];
//        $data['currency_code'] = $paypalInfo["cc"];
//        $data['status'] = $paypalInfo["st"];
//        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
//        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
//        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
//        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
//        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
//        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
//        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
//        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
        //pass the transaction data to view

        var_dump(fsockopen ('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30));
        var_dump($_POST);
     }

     function cancel(){
//        $this->load->view('paypal/cancel');
         echo "Cancelled";
     }

     function ipn(){
        //paypal return transaction details array
        $paypalInfo    = $this->input->post();

        $data['user_id'] = $paypalInfo['custom'];
        $data['product_id']    = $paypalInfo["item_number"];
        $data['txn_id']    = $paypalInfo["txn_id"];
        $data['payment_gross'] = $paypalInfo["mc_gross"];
        $data['currency_code'] = $paypalInfo["mc_currency"];
        $data['payer_email'] = $paypalInfo["payer_email"];
        $data['payment_status']    = $paypalInfo["payment_status"];

        $paypalURL = $this->paypal_lib->paypal_url;  
//        $paypalURL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';          
        $result    = $this->paypal_lib->curlPost($paypalURL,$paypalInfo);

        //check whether the payment is verified
        if(preg_match("/VERIFIED/i",$result)){
            //insert the transaction data into the database
//            $this->product->insertTransaction($data);
            var_dump("IPN SUCCESS");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your ipn function where you want to receive the response,

```
// STEP 1: read POST data
// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream.
$raw_post_data  = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost         = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
log_message('error', "IPN DATA: " . $req);
```

To check ipn response, check the log, in logs folder

And for more info [click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/)

And one more thing you have set ipn url as below, so paypal will send response on "Notification" function in your controller

```
$notifyURL = site_url(AGENT_ROLE.$this->data['controller']."/Notification"); //ipn url
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. How would this look in my ipn function? What do I send back to Paypal? This seems to write this to a log file only.

Comment: By the way,  do I have to set or change items such as PDT?

Comment: Did you got response from ipn?

Comment: Paypal send IPN reponse to your sever, not to your browser,so you can't use `var_dump` or `print_r` for it(you must use log to see the response). The IPN code i gave, is a sample, Use log to manage your code as you want.

Comment: May I know where the log files get written to? At the moment I haven't seemed to set any location for it.

Comment: . I have tried to run the code again and payments have been successful. But the IPN still returns nothing and I cannot find the log files

Comment: Your function name for ipn?

Comment: check logs documentation is codeigniter https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html#log_message

Comment: I have tried searching for it. your code doesn't produce any logs. My ipn is the one you specified the /Notification one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153006/discussion-between-parth-and-jianya).

Comment: Sorry, I have decided to try another method. Thank you for your help so far. I really appreciate it.